# WPF Datagrid add List<double> as column

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm not new to programming, but I encountered a lot of unexcpected problems with WPF DataGrid.
Let's start by saying I want to add a column for each collection programmatically, without any Binding.

```
List<List<double>> collection = new List<List<double>> {
    new List<double>() {1.5, 2.5, 3.5},
    new List<double>() {1.5, 2.5},
    new List<double>() {1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5}
};
```

I want 3 columns, each one for a List, and 4 rows. Obviously some of them are going to be empty.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Typically DataGrids are bound in WPF. It's not very handy to add rows and columns in code behind. Do you really need to add rows in code behind?

Comment: Bind ItemsSource to a DataTable or an ObservableCollection of a class that has one property (not field) for each column. You’re setting out to fight WPF here. Don’t waste your time. WPF will win.

Comment: I would prefer not to bind anything, but maybe it could be something I could deal with. Anyway: how can I do it WITH binding?

Comment: Please try to give us some more context. Explain your problem, the structure of your application, some code and the point to add the rows.

Comment: Is your DataGrid readOnly?

Comment: Man, I think you're completly misunderstand how WPF `DataGrid` work. `DataGrid` simply treat `ItemsSource` like a data table. It see every element in the collection as a row, and every public property in those elements as a column. So, it would not work like you expected.

Comment: I tried to use the DataTable and then assign to dataGrid.DataContext the dataTable.DefaultView. I also tried adding new Items as an array of strings, but it just doesn't display anything.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @GiacomoAscari `DataContext` property is default binding source of a `FrameworkElement`, so just set a collection to it would change anything if you didn't use any binding. Just set a `string[]` to `ItemsSource`, you will see a "Lenght" column that show you all lenghts of every string in that array, because `String` class only has one public property `Lenght`. Of cause you can customize how `DataGrid` display data that set to its `ItemsSource`, please check out MSDN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a DataTable, it'll probably give more flexibility for other things you might want to do like edit...

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("Value1", typeof(double));
DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("Value2", typeof(double));
DataColumn dc3 = new DataColumn("Value3", typeof(double));
DataColumn dc4 = new DataColumn("Value4", typeof(double));

dt.Columns.Add(dc1);
dt.Columns.Add(dc2);
dt.Columns.Add(dc3);
dt.Columns.Add(dc4);

DataGrid dg = new DataGrid()
{
    ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView,
    Background = Brushes.Wheat,
    AlternatingRowBackground = Brushes.AliceBlue,
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto,
    Height = 500,
    Width = 400,
};

dt.Rows.Add(1.5, 2.5, 3.5);
dt.Rows.Add(1.5, 2.5, null);
dt.Rows.Add(1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5);

MyCanvas.Children.Add(dg);  // A canvas in the XAML
Canvas.SetTop(10,dg);
Canvas.SetLeft(10,dg);
```